# php validation not working using from validation

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
  $pass = $_POST['uname'];
  if($pass=="")
  {
    $status="must be field out";
exit();
  }
  else if(strlen($pass<=4))
  {
    $status="password must be 8 charters";
    exit();
  }
  else
  {
    $status="ok";
    exit;
  }
}   
?>
  <body>
    <p><?php echo $status; ?></p>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
      <span>username:</span><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="checkme"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

without click any button echo notification show in the page if all condition is true `stattus="ok";` not working
any tutorial for beginners please help me

Comment: learn to understand what EXIT() does => http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Answer (score 0):

With `exit()` you cancel the execution of your PHP-file, so everything after a exit() call will not be displayed.

If you think that the other parts of your if statement get reached...no. The next part (else part) of an if statement get's only reached if the condition (in if(condition)) before is false.

Remove the `exit()` calls and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `exit()` commands. These are causing the script to stop before it gets to the echo of the message

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
echo $status;
```

If you are loading the page at which point the $_REQUEST or $_POST are not set, $status is undefined and never set. So you would see an error saying it is an undefined variable.

To fix this, you can

1. add to the top of the script

   ```
   $status = "";
   ```
2. Or while print $status do the following

   ```
   echo isset($status) ? $status : "";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $pass=$_POST['uname'];
    if(trim($_POST['uname']) == ''){
        $err['uname'] = 'must be field out';
    }
    else if(strlen($pass)<=4)
    {
        $err['uname'] = 'password must be 8 charters';
    }
    else{
        $err['uname']="ok";
    }
}

?>

<body>

        <form method="post" action="">
           <span>username:</span><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" />
           <?php if($err['uname'] != '') { ?>
                    <p style="color: red;" class="error">
                        <?php echo $err['uname'];?>
                    </p>
                    <?php }  ?>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="checkme"/>
            </form>
       </body>
```

Comment: @user3164111 try this code and let me info this is help to you.